# Why does this code lead to "heap corruption detected"?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with my code, and I don't understand what is wrong with it.

This is the were the problem occurs in the code:

```
void Safe_Array::resize(unsigned new_capacity)
{
    score += sizeof(int)*(new_capacity - m_capacity);

    if (m_capacity < new_capacity)
    {
        int old_len = m_capacity - 1;

        Safe_Array temp(*this);

        if (m_data)
            delete[] m_data;
        m_data = new int[sizeof(int)*new_capacity]; // new allocation
        m_capacity = new_capacity;

        for (int i = 0; i < old_len + 1; i++)
            m_data[i] = temp.m_data[i];

        for (; old_len < new_capacity; old_len++)
            m_data[old_len] = 0;
    }

    else // here we need to shorten the array
    {
        Safe_Array temp(*this);

        if (m_data)
            delete[] m_data;
        m_data = new int[sizeof(int)*new_capacity]; // new allocation
        m_capacity = new_capacity;

        for (int i = 0; i < new_capacity; i++)
            m_data[i] = temp.m_data[i];
    }
}
```

I encounter the error when I try to `delete m_data`.

The purpose of this function:

first I have created an object that m_data is its array, resize is a function that will as it say "resize" this field of the object.

Here is the Header file:

```
class Safe_Array
{
public:
    Safe_Array(unsigned capacity = 0, const int max_tries = 3);
    Safe_Array(const Safe_Array&);
    ~Safe_Array();

    void show(void) const;
    unsigned get_capacity() const;
    bool insert(int, unsigned);
    bool get(unsigned index, int &value) const;
    bool search(int value, unsigned &index) const;
    Safe_Array& assign(const Safe_Array&);
    void resize(unsigned);
    void sort();
    static unsigned get_score();

    friend int compare(const Safe_Array& a, const Safe_Array& b);

    Safe_Array& create(unsigned index1, unsigned index2);

private:
    int *m_data;
    unsigned m_capacity;
    static unsigned score;
    const int m_max_tries;
    unsigned int counter;
};
```

Here is the cpp file of the function. (including distractor, contractor, copy contractor, and the function resize):

```
Safe_Array::Safe_Array(unsigned capacity, int max_tries) : 
m_max_tries(max_tries), m_capacity(0), m_data(NULL), counter(0)
{
        m_capacity = capacity;
        //counter = 0; // when created counter = 0
        m_data = new int[capacity];
        memset(m_data, 0, m_capacity*sizeof(int));

    score += sizeof(Safe_Array) + sizeof(int)*m_capacity;
}

Safe_Array::Safe_Array(const Safe_Array& org_obj) : 
m_max_tries(org_obj.m_max_tries), m_capacity(org_obj.m_capacity), counter(0) // copy constractor
{
    m_data = new int[m_capacity];
    memcpy(m_data, org_obj.m_data, m_capacity * sizeof(int)); // copy sizeof(int)*4 -> int is 4 bytes & memcpy copies bytes
    score += sizeof(Safe_Array) + sizeof(int)*m_capacity;
}

Safe_Array::~Safe_Array() // distractor
{
    if (m_data) // check if object exists
        delete[] m_data;
    score -= sizeof(Safe_Array) + sizeof(int)*m_capacity; // uptade score
}
```

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. It would help explain many things, including whether your violating the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), what the purpose of the mysterious `score` variable is, etc. Please include *all* code required for **us** to copy/paste/compile/reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is the copy-constructor working correctly? You follow [the rules of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) otherwise?

Comment: Oh and you don't need to make a copy at all. Save the pointer `m_data` in a temporary variable, allocate new memory (assigning to `m_data`), copy the old data, and free the old data pointed to by the temporary variable. And this can be done for both enlarging and shrinking, in a *common* branch.

Comment: can I add files here? I have a header file, a cpp file (for the functions) and app file for testing the code.

Comment: @Twins96 you can edit your question to add source code. But probably you don't have the right copy constructor as it was said, so correct it (this is the best thing to do) or do the _delete_ later as I did in my answer. Note that to clone the current instance can be very expensive and complicated for nothing

Comment: By the way, when using `new[]` the size you provide is the number of *elements*, not the amount of bytes. That means `new int[sizeof(int) * new_capacity]` will allocate four times (for 32-bit `int`) time as many elements than you need.

Comment: @Twins96 *// here we need to shorten the array* -- Why?  There is no need to do that -- that's the purpose for `capacity`.  Just set the `size` to the smaller size.  You're also missing the assignment operator.

Comment: the array need to be sorted: if I have an array and I just want to keep the first 5 elements of it, then I will use this function. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Instead of tracking everything as an array why not just use `std::vector<int>`?  Seems like it would be easier to manage.

Comment: @Twins96 -- What does the array being sorted have to do with needlessly creating a smaller array?  For example, you have an array that has a size of 100 elements, and now you want to make it 80 elements.  All you need to do is set the `size()` to 80 -- the extra 20 elements -- who cares, let them stay there.  The class now checks for accesses above index 79.  That is exactly how `std::vector` does things -- no need to allocate data that already exists.  That's why you really need two variables, one to hold the valid max size, and another for the capacity.

Comment: Given the code posted, I don't see how the heap corruption would occur. Although there are some questionable ways of doing things. Try to reduce the full program to a [mcve]. That means stripping away all the functions that are no needed, everything except constructors, destructor, `resize` and the test code, as much as possible without the error disappearing.

Comment: I mean **shorted** sorry for the misunderstanding. But I don't want the rest element to stay. isn't that a waste of memory? And I didn't understand what you meant by: "The class now checks for accesses above 79." @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Twins96 -- The class you created should have two member variables, `size` and `capacity`.  The `size` is the number of logical elements.  The user cannot access beyond this number.  The `capacity` is the number of elements you have in reserve, so that you don't needlessly have to reallocate each and every time the user calls `resize()`.  Get it now?

Comment: However note that your code does not work with a capacity of zero. Is that the issue? (because of  `m_data[old_len] = 0;` with `old_len == -1`) Actually I think that is a mistake. You probably want to start at `old_len+1` in that loop.

Comment: @Twins96 -- It is not a waste of memory.  It is a balance between speed and memory, and speed will win here.  Your code will attempt to `new` and `delete`, even if the resize() is one less than the current capacity.  For example, if the current size is 100, and the user asks for a resize to 99, you do the `new` and `delete` dance for one element.  Does that make sense to waste all of that energy?  [Here is an example of a simple vector class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d4d62a0ae1c868b).  It doesn't do everything, but it does show the beginnings of how to create such a class properly.

Comment: yes, thank you @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @user10605163, no It is not the problem. but you are right that I need to check this special case

Comment: @Twins96 I don't think it is a special case, you are setting the last element of the original array to zero in any case. You should start one higher always.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- yes you are write, I am just beginning to work with classes, sorry that it looks to amateurish.

Comment: @user10605163 -- in the case of `m_data[old_len] = 0;` I need to make the array larger and the assignment was to insert 0 to the new cells

Comment: @Twins96 Suppose `m_capacity == 1` when resizing to `new_capacity == 2`. Then the original array has only one element `m_data[0]`. Now `old_len` is set to `m_capacity - 1`, i.e. `0`. Then in the first for loop you copy `temp.m_data[0]` to `m_data[0]`, but in the second loop you also overwrite `m_data[0]` with `0`, because `old_len` is `0` and smaller than `new_capacity`. You want to start one higher up. I understand that you want to set `m_data[1]` then to zero. But your second loop does too much.

Answer (score 2):

probably `Safe_Array temp(*this);` do not copy (deeply) `m_data`, so after the delete you look at a freed memory.

Moving the delete later :

```
if (m_data) {
  int * old = m_data;

  m_data = new int[sizeof(int)*new_capacity]; // new allocation
  m_capacity = new_capacity;

  for (int i = 0; i < old_len + 1; i++)
     m_data[i] = old[i];

  delete[] old;
}
```

To clone the current instance just to (hope to) save a member of it is a bad way.